# Reload tableView after Alert dismiss?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to call table.reloadData() when I dismiss my UIAlertController. But I don't know how to do it.

I tried putting table.reloadData() in ViewController's viewWillAppear but it doesn't work because Alert's modalPresentationStyle cannot be changed.

I'm presenting alertController like so:

```
`let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Enter a text", preferredStyle: .alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
 let enteredTitle = alert!.textFields![0]
 let enteredNoteDescription = alert!.textFields![1]
 
 //Save to DB
 let note = Note(context: CoreDataService.managedObjectContext)
 note.title = enteredTitle.text
 note.noteDescription = enteredNoteDescription.text
 CoreDataService.saveContext()
 }))

present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`
```

Comment: You added `UIAlertAction` on your `alert` no? Reload on the action completion.

Comment: I did, just didn't mention that in the question

Comment: edited my question, where is completion?

Comment: It's the `handler`. So call `table.reloadData()` just after `saveContext()`.

Comment: alert?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
 self.tableView.reloadData()
 }) didn't work

Comment: Because that's the completion of the presentation, meaning, once the alert has been presented, not once it has dismissed. It's the actions that dismiss.

Comment: Added table.reloadData() just after saveContext() -> didn't work

Comment: What's the code of ` CoreDataService.saveContext()`? Is it asynchrone ? You did add the `reloadData()` inside `handler`, right?

Comment: Where are you dismissing the alert? Please add clear code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func showErrorAlertWithAction( withTitle: String,
                               andMessage: String,
                               buttonName: String,
                               completion: @escaping (() -> Void))
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: withTitle, message: andMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: buttonName, style: .default) { _ in completion() }
    alert.addAction(action)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Usage is:

```
    showErrorAlertWithAction(withTitle: "Some Title", andMessage: "Enter a text", buttonName: "OK") {
        // here you use action that will take effect after user taps "OK" button e.g:
        //Save to DB
        let note = Note(context: CoreDataService.managedObjectContext)
        note.title = enteredTitle.text
        note.noteDescription = enteredNoteDescription.text
        CoreDataService.saveContext()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this solution and worked with me:

Suppose that your data source is:

```
var elements = ["first", "second", "third"]
```

and then your alert creation be like this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Enter a text", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
     self?.elements.append("forth")
     self?.tableView.reloadData()
}))
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So As you see I've reloaded the table view in the action handler completion using **self?.tableView.reloadData()** and the worked fine with me.
let me know if it didn't work with you